# strncpy char string issue when adding length

Tags: c++, strcmp, strcpy, strncpy

I'm having a problem with comparing 2 char strings that are both the same:

```
char string[50];

strncpy(string, "StringToCompare", 49);

if( !strcmp("StringToCompare", string) )
//do stuff
else
//the code runs into here even tho both strings are the same...this is what the problem is.
```

If I use:

`strcpy(string, "StringToCompare");`

instead of:

`strncpy(string, "StringToCompare", 49);`

it solves the problem, but I would rather insert the length of the string rather than it getting it itself.

What's going wrong here? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Wrong is that you are using c strings, instead of std::string

Comment: You have to add the end of string '\0' because you are declaring "string" as a vector of chars, and not as a string.

Comment: Is the string in the "real world" 49 characters long by any chance?

Comment: @VJovic And what makes you so sure STL is available on his target platform? Or that not using STL was his decision?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: first of all, you are probably talking about C++ Standard Library, not STL, which are independent libraries. Secondly, do you know any not-cross-platform implementations of std::string? All it requires is memory allocator, so why would it be platform-dependant? Lastly, _why would anyone avoid C++ **Standard** Library and use obsolete C functions?_ Better to move back to C, as C++ is no longer "C with classes".

Comment: @Griwes tell a C programmer that C functions are "obsolete"...

Comment: @H2CO3, "obsolete" in context of using C++, of course... I thought everyone would figure it out...

Comment: OK, I see... Anyway, you're right that probably one should use the standard C++ library as much as possible, but if C-style functions were obsolete, in my opinion, C would only provide classes with methods, and not alone functions.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't have the problem you describe. The problem almost certainly lies in the code you *didn't* post. Please create a **small**, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. For more info see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: My official guess: OP is passing `strlen(src)`, not `sizeof(dest)` as the third parameter to `strncpy`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put a terminating NUL character to `string`, so maybe strcmp run over the end. Use this line of code:

```
string[49] = '\0';
```

to solve your problem.

Comment: That could be the problem in his real example, but not in his posted test case. From the Linux man page: "If the length of `src` is less than `n`, `strncpy()` pads  the  remainder  of `dest` with null bytes."

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the null terminator manually when using `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(string, "StringToCompare", 48);
string[49] = 0;
```

Comment: only if the string was too long.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of apparent guesses in the other answers, but a quick suggestion.

First of all, the code as written should work (and in fact, does work in Visual Studio 2010).  The key is in the details of ['strncpy'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) -- it will not implicity add a `null` terminating character unless the source length is less than the destination length (which it is in this case).  [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) on the other hand does include the `null` terminator in all cases, suggesting that your compiler isn't properly handling the `strncpy` function.

So, if this isn't working on your compiler, you should likely initialize your temporary buffer like this:

```
char string[50] = {0}; // initializes all the characters to 0

// below should be 50, as that is the number of 
// characters available in the string (not 49).
strncpy(string, "StringToCompare", 50);
```

However, I suspect this is likely just an example, and in the real world your source string is 49 (again, you should pass 50 to `strncpy` in this case) characters or longer, in which case the NULL terminator is NOT being copied into your temporary string.

I would echo the suggestions in the comments to use `std::string` if available.  It takes care of all of this for you, so you can focus on your implementation rather than these trite details.

Answer (score 0):

The byte count parameter in `strncpy` tells the function how many bytes to copy, not the length of the character buffer.

So in your case you are asking to copy 49 bytes from your constant string into the buffer, which I don't think is your intent!

However, it doesn't explain why you are getting the anomalous result.  What compiler are you using? When I run this code under VS2005 I get the correct behavior.

Note that `strncpy()` has been deprecated in favor of `strncpy_s`, which does want the buffer length passed to it:

```
strncpy_s (string,sizeof(string),"StringToCompare",49)
```

Comment: check the documentation of [strncpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdsywd25(v=vs.80).aspx)... `If count is greater than the length of strSource, the destination string is padded with null characters up to length count.`... that is to say it won't copy into "StringToCompare" beyond sizeof("StringToCompare")... +1 for emphasis on `strncpy_s`

Answer (score -1):

`strcopy` and `strncpy`: in this situation they behave identically!!

So you didn't tell us the truth or the whole picture (eg: the string is at least 49 characters long)